# Should I be accessing Map Reduce output as a Mongoid Document?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mapreduce, mongoid, state-machine

So my map reduce operation sums up a list of micro payments into a lump sum that I owe a particular user.  The user_id ends up being the _id.  I also store an array ids of the micro payments that need to be paid.  The output goes into a permeant collection called payments.

The output looks like this for one document

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4f48855606164f4765000004"), "value" : { "payment" : "5.0", "conversions" : [ ObjectId("4f5bd23baa113e964700000e") ] } }
```

I'd kind of like to track these payments so I was thinking about just building a mongoid document around the payments collection.  I kind of know it can be done but I haven't really seen anyone doing it so it makes me think there must be a better way.

Also one problem with this approach is I'm making the payments every month so the _id being the user_id is going to conflict.  Additionally I think there is a possible transaction problem because I need to update the micro payments to a different state so I know not to pay them ever again and what happens if one of the payments fails?  These state change via [state_machine](https://github.com/pluginaweek/state_machine) if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Should I be accessing Map Reduce output as a Mongoid Document?

Sure you can definitely do this. That's kind of the reason the M/R is output to a collection rather than just "some file".

> Also one problem with this approach is I'm making the payments every month so the _id being the user_id is going to conflict.

So clearly, the output of your M/R is important data. Do not leave this data in a collection that could be "hammered" by a future M/R. Instead, rename the collection you have created, or run a `for` loop that manually appends the data to a "keeper" collection.

In the "keeper" collection change the `_id` to something like `_id: { uid: ObjectId('...'), month: "201203" }`. You may also want to "fan out" the `values` field into several fields. And you will need to add a field for transaction ID.

Also remember that MongoDB uses "fire & forget" writes by default. These are low safety. You have financial data, so ensure that you are following all of the best practices for availability and data safety:

- Journaling On
- Replica Sets (with secondary data center)
- Ensure that all writes to this collection/db are done with `w: majority` and `journal: true`. This will slow down DB throughput on this operation as these writes can take a few hundred milliseconds.
- Database passwords
- Non-standard MongoDB port, IP white-listing (usual DB security)

> what happens if one of the payments fails?

This a non-trivial problem and way too complicated to explain here. Instead, see this document on the [two-phase commit with MongoDB](http://cookbook.mongodb.org/patterns/perform-two-phase-commits/).

Note that two-phase commit requires MongoDB's `findAndModify` command. You will have to learn how to handle this with Mongoid.